# How to change build path in vscode flutter extention?

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I need to change build path to avoid syncing it with cloud.

I am compiling for android.

I created a new flutter project and changed this line in `android/build.gradle`:

```
rootProject.buildDir = 'C:/build'
```

It works and I can see `app-debug.apk` file in `c:/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk`.

But then I am getting exception:

> Exception: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under
> C:\Users\brand17\YandexDisk\Software\flutter\scooter\build, but the
> tool couldn't find it.

So the framework looks for `.apk` in the old folder.

I tried `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` - it doesn't help.

Comment: do you use `flavors` in your app ?

Comment: @inkredusk no, I don't